# Как отключить автопроигрывание в Slick?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Пытаюсь отключить autoplay в слайдере slick на нажатие точки
Нашла такие варианты, но не работает
// в целом не срабатывает, наверное я что-то не поняла в оформлении

```
$('.my-dots').find('button').click(function(){
    // $('.single-item-main').slick('slickSetOption', 'autoplay', false).slick('slickPause');
    // $('.single-item-main').slick('slickPause');
    // $('.single-item-main').slick('slickSetOption', { 'autoplay': false }, false); 
  });
```

сам слайдер

```
$('.single-item-main').slick({
    draggable: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    accessibility: false,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    dotsClass: "my-dots",
    pauseOnDotsHover: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
  });
```

с такой настройкой, при нажатии на кнопку слайдер и сам останавливается, но только пока в фокусе
если кликнуть по другому объекту на странице анимация продолжается
подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка, ну или другое решение
а то информации больше найти не получается :(

Comment: У вас же есть параметр опции `pauseOnDotsHover - Пауза автопроигрывания при наведении мыши на навигационные точки` Так же вы можете использовать такие параметры как `slickNext — прокручивает на один слайд вперёд`, `slickGoTo — переходит к слайду с указанным номером`, `slickPrev — прокручивает на один слайд назад`, `slickPause — останавливает автоматическую прокрутку`, `slickPlay — запускает автоматическую прокрутку`,
`$('.single-item').slick('slickGoTo',4);
$().slick('slickPrev');
$().slick('slickNext');
$().slick('slickPause');
$().slick('slickPlay');
`

Comment: Благодарю за уделённое время, к сожалению информация не была полезна, но всё равно спасибо)
Нужно отключение именно после нажатия, не при наведении
slickPause полезный метод) он мне и нужен, просто не работал

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает... проблема была в том, что скрипт был подключён 2 раза, ох уж эти глупые ошибки.
Если кому-то понадобится отключение slick слайдера при нажатии на dots:

```
$('yourslider').slick({
    // настройки ваши
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    dotsClass: "my-dots",
});
$('.my-dots').find('button').click(function(){
    $('yourslider').slick('slickPause'); 
});
```

Что-то такое